# How to filter Facebook events by country in Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-events

I'm trying to search public events on Facebook using the Graph API.

http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=term&type=event

I've noticed that most of the results are irrelevant. For example, I'm in the UK and the search return events happening in Asia or America. How can I get only events from the UK? I was thinking about using the timezone but I'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks!